# Unrestricted MIDAS model selection with midasr, follow up question

Tags: r, economics, midasr

My question is essentially the same as in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148448/model-selection-with-unrestricted-model-in-midasr-package), however the answer given wasn't especially exhaustive in that `midas_r_ic_table` must take the "table" argument, a table that can be generated via  `expand_weights_lags`, another function that requires restrictions. Thus, even though `midas_r_ic_table` can output the model selection for an unrestricted model, to me it seems not possible to generate model selection where I have not already imposed a certain structure. Is there a way around this that I am not aware of?

If not, then my next question concerns model selection without `midas_r_ic_table`. Since midas_u is simply a wrapper for lm according to the documentation, I am wondering if there is a way to feed an unrestricted MIDAS model to existing model selection functions, or stepwise selection functions in R that are designed for linear models.

For context, I am fitting a RU-MIDAS model of the form :

```
mdl <- midas_r(mlsd(y,2,x)~mlsd(x, 1:3, x)+ mlsd(z, 1:3, x) +
                   mlsd(w, 1:3, x) + 
                  +mlsd(y,3+0:3, x), data=list(dmx, dtx), start = NULL)
```

[an example with reproducible code can be found here.](https://mpiktas.github.io/reverse-midas/reverse_midasr_example.html) It suffices to try running midas_r_ic_table on the fitted model without table arguments.